# swift protocol, IBOutlet property cannot have non-object type

Tags: ios, interface-builder, swift

I would like to wire up a custom swift delegate in IB. The delegate is an object that implements a certain protocol in swift.

```
protocol ThumbnailTableViewCellDelegate {
    func cellWasTouched(thumbnail: Bool, cell: UITableViewCell)
}

class ThumbnailTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var thumbnailTableViewCellDelegate: ThumbnailTableViewCellDelegate?
}
```

unfortunately, the compiler complains with:

```
error: 'IBOutlet' property cannot have non-object type 'ThumbnailTableViewCellDelegate'
    @IBOutlet var thumbnailTableViewCellDelegate: ThumbnailTableViewCellDelegate?
    ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: @Andy It's perfectly okay - you're saying it is an object that conforms to that protocol.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You have to declare your `ThumbnailTableViewCellDelegate` protocol as `@objc`:

```
@objc protocol ThumbnailTableViewCellDelegate {
    func cellWasTouched(thumbnail: Bool, cell: UITableViewCell)
}
```

This is because `@IBOutlet` declares the variable as `weak`, which only works with objects. I'm not sure why you can't just say the protocol conforms to `AnyObject`, perhaps that's a Swift bug.

Comment: Thanks Nate, that worked! Is this a temporary workaround or expected behavior? What is the relevance of @objc in this case?

Comment: This method is no longer working for me (using the GM seed of Xcode 6.)

Comment: This compiles but I'm having issues actually connecting the outlet in the storyboard now

Comment: yes, same on xcode 6.2 ... anyone has resolved this?

Comment: you can either use the workaround by Morten J below, or set the delegate manually in code instead of in the storyboard. If you have no reference to the ThumbnailTableViewCell yet, you have to create an outlet first.

Comment: instead of having an `@objc protocol`, you can declare your protocol as class-only, like this: `protocol ThumbnailTableViewCellDelegate: class` for the same effect and without the possible disadvantages of Xcode forcing you to have this protocol compliant with Objective-C

Comment: ten years later, note this is now the **correct and only solution**.  it is commonplace and works 100% of the time.

Answer (score 13):

You can in connect your own protocols in IB with this workaround. It's a known issue with Xcode, so will probably be solved one day. Until then:

1. Declare the delegate as an AnyObject - @IBOutlet var delegate:AnyObject!
2. Connect the delegate in Interface Builder
3. Change the outlet's type to your protocol, e.g. @IBOutlet var delegate:MyDelegate

This works for me.

Comment: Is there a known radar or release note where this is documented?

Comment: Note, ten years later **don't do this** !

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but an option is to do something like this:

```
@IBOutlet var objectType: NSObject!

private var conformingObject: SomeProtocol {
  return objectType as SomeProtocol
}
```

Got to make sure your `objectType` conforms to `SomeProtocol` or things will explode

Answer (score 0):

A variable of protocol type might not be an object, because structs and enums can conform to protocols too. To ensure that a protocol can only be conformed to by classes, you can declare the protocol with `@class_protocol`.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of makes sense that IB requires AnyObject, rather than your particular protocol.  The object you want to connect to probably, but not necessarily conforms to the protocol, and the protocol may have optionals - so:

Make your protocol like this:

```
@objc public protocol HexViewDataSource: NSObjectProtocol {
    @objc optional func dataAtOffset (_ hexView: HexView, offset: UInt64, length: Int)-> Data?
    @objc optional func dataLength (_ hexView: HexView) -> UInt64
}
```

Declare it in your class like this, for instance:

```
@IBOutlet weak open var dataSource: AnyObject?
```

And when you come to use it, check that it conforms to the protocol and that the optionals exist - like this:

```
if let dataSource = dataSource as? HexViewDataSource, let dfr = dataSource.dataAtOffset {
    setRowData(offset: offset, data: dfr (self, offset, bytesPerRow))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### For 2023 ...

You simply have to add `@objc`before the protocol definition.

You **do not have to make ANY changes** in the view controllers.

Example:

```
@objc protocol VideoControls {
    var playButton: UIButton! { get }
    var pauseButton: UIButton! { get }
    var timeText: UILabel! { get }
```

and then in a view controller ...

```
class CompactPlayer: UIViewController, VideoControls {
    @IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var pauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var timeText: UILabel!
```

and

```
class FullScreenPlayer: UIViewController, VideoControls {
    @IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var pauseButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var timeText: UILabel!
```

That's it.

Answer (score -2):

IBOutlets are to indicate a pointer to an object stored in a nib (or storyboard) file. A protocol is not an object, therefore you can't have one in a nib file. Make the type of the IBOutlet var to be the type of the actual object you have in the nib.