# Swift correct declaration of object corresponding to protocol and having superclass

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard

I am Swift beginner and really stuck with this problem.

I have a prototype cell `CurrencySwitchTableViewCell` that is subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

```
class CurrencySwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
       @IBOutlet weak internal var currencySwitchDelegate: AnyObject!
```

This cell has a `currencySwitchDelegate` property that should be of `CurrencySwitchDelegate` protocol

```
protocol CurrencySwitchDelegate {
   func didSelectCurrency(currency:Currency)
}
```

How can I declare in `CurrencySwitchTableViewCell` that my `currencySwitchDelegate` is `AnyObject` corresponding to `CurrencySwitchDelegate` protocol?

What is Swift analog of Objective-C code like this?

`NSObject<CurrencySwitchDelegate>` or `id<CurrencySwitchDelegate>`

P.S.

I know I can just declare my property to be

```
@IBOutlet weak internal var currencySwitchDelegate: CurrencySwitchDelegate!
```

But XCode gives me error with `@IBOutlet` modifier (IBOutlets should be of `AnyObject` class)

Comment: I too am a beginner with Swift, but don't you need to declare then that the `CurrencySwitchDelegate` is a protocol of `AnyObject`?

Comment: why do you use @IBOutlet? are you connecting something via interface builder? normally it should just be something like `var currencySwitchDelegate: CurrencySwitchDelegate?`

Comment: I am using iboutlet to set connection from my cell to viewcontroller that implements this protocol

Comment: are you using static cells? cause if not that won't work. you have to set the delegate in code (when the cells are instantiated). that means you can and should delete that IBOutlet stuff.

Comment: @DanF thanks for your suggestion, it doesn't work that way (I have the same error) But I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561490/swift-protocol-iboutlet-property-cannot-have-non-object-type

Comment: @AndreSlotta  I understand this and was doing this kind of things all my life before but wanted to try moving maximum logic to storyboard. I have dynamic cells. when uitableview deques cells from reusable deque, it sets all IBOutlet properties correctly. Why this won't work with delegate which is also defined in storyboard?

Comment: I tried the solution with @objc before protocol declaration and everything works fine. But it looks strange for me and seems that setting up delegate from code is a much cleaner solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: but even with @objc before protocol declaration it is not possible to connect the outlet via storyboard, is it?

Comment: It's possible but having @objc before protocol forces us to use only objc-compatible types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object have often a weak reference to the delegate and only objects can become weak references. You can inform the compiler that the delegate is an object by using `: class`

```
protocol CurrencySwitchDelegate: class {
   func didSelectCurrency(currency:Currency)
}
```

For the moment Xcode cannot IBOutlet protocol. The temporary solution is to create an other IBOutlet of type AnyObject and then cast it in your code.

```
@IBOutlet weak internal var outletDelegate: AnyObject?

private var delegate: CurrencySwitchDelegate? {
    return self.outletDelegate as! CurrencySwitchDelegate?
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tried this way too, it works but i don't like the boilerplate typecasting code

Comment: Yes I don't like too but it's the only way until Xcode supports it. The other solution is to use @objc but you couldn't use swift feature like optional, ... in the method of your protocol if you use it because of the objective-c compatibility.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the extended explanation!