# How to connect delegate from custom class in xib?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, xib, iboutlet

I have created a class "DeletableImageView" (.swift + .xib) which uses the protocol I defined as "DeletableImageViewDelegate" through a property I called delegate.

Example for sake of clarity:

**DeletableImageView.swift**

```
protocol DeletableImageViewDelegate {
    func deleteImageWithTag(tag: Int!) -> (Bool)
    func addImageOnViewWithTag(tag: Int!) -> (Bool)
    ...
}

class DeletableImageView: UIView {

    var view: UIView!
    var delegate: DeletableImageViewDelegate?

    // Some random methods + some use of the delegate protocol's methods
    ...
}
```

My problem is that now, when I try to use my class in a controller from the associated .xib file (which means that I drag and drop a view in interface builder and assign the DeletableImageView class to this view) I cannot link the delegate property (even if I declare this property as an IBOutlet).

What I want to be able to do is to directly **link the view's delegate outlet to the "File's Owner" in the .xib**

The exact same thing you do when you link datasource and delegate from a tableview directly in the .xib file.

But when I control-drag they won't link together.

Does anyone have any idea of what is happening ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does the file owner conform to the protocol?

Comment: Yes the file owner conforms to the protocol ...

Comment: Here is a video I made to help you understand my problem : https://youtu.be/clYFj6dkaWk

Comment: looks like a bug to me - can reproduce the issue. I can connect to classes, but not protocols.

Comment: a pretty old bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561490/swift-protocol-iboutlet-property-cannot-have-non-object-type and https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13465 AAAAND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180268/interface-builder-iboutlet-and-protocols-for-delegate-and-datasource-in-swift :/

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 !! You're right, it is a bug ! When I change the delegate property type to AnyObject it works ! :D

Answer (score 5):

First thing you need to do is to add `@objc` in from of your protocol definition, so that it looks like:

```
@objc protocol DeletableImageViewDelegate {
    ...
}
```

You might ask why do you need to do this. It's because you want to add delegate property to the storyboard, and in order to set some property visible by storyboard, it must have `@IBOutlet` prefix, and that prefix requires it to be Objective C protocol.

So the next thing you want to do is change `var delegate: DeletableImageViewDelegate?` to

```
@IBOutlet var delegate: DeletableImageViewDelegate?
```

Now if you right click on the view in the interface builder you will get something like this, which means that we exposed our delegate property to the interface builder.
[image: Exposed property]

If you try to connect it to file owner (for example `UIViewController`), it will not work because your file owner still doesn't implement that protocol. To implement it you need to write:

```
extension UIViewController : DeletableImageViewDelegate {
    // Implementation
}
```

After you do that, you should be able to connect delegate property to the view controller, thus receiving delegate method messages. In each case your file owner must implement the protocol.

Comment: I tried it but it's still not working, I'm starting to wonder if this might be a bug of XCode cause the new version has a lot of problem with my .xib(s) or maybe it's juste on my mac ...

It's still not possible to link the view to the file ower ...

I would like to precise that I ** DON'T USE STORYBOARDS !!!**, maybe this is why it is not working ?

Comment: Here is a video I made to help you understand my problem : https://youtu.be/clYFj6dkaWk

Comment: Now I see that your deletable view is a subview of the main view in the xib. Add extension to the `UIView` and you should be good.

Comment: It was a bug, @luk2302 was right, I changed the delegate property to type to "AnyObject" and now it works ! :)

Anyway, thank you both of you !

Answer (score 0):

I've created solution similar as in the comments. But I've also wanted not have to cast delegate every time and check for protocol implementation.

```
weak var delegate: MenuViewDelegate?
@IBOutlet weak var _delegate: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        if let d = _delegate {
            if let d = (d as? MenuViewDelegate) {
                delegate = d
            } else {
                print("ERROR: delegate does not implement \(d) MenuViewDelegate protocol")

                d as! MenuViewDelegate
            }
        }
    }
}
```